# Which video streamming flux FLASH can open?

Tags: actionscript, streaming, flash, actionscript-2

I need to show a live video show on my website, I want something that doesn't need the user to install any plugin like wmv in firefox for example, then I think flash is the only way.
But can flash open something else than flv ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Flash player supports more than one video codec

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402866.html